# Load-time weaving with AspectJ in the Spring Framework Private methods

Tags: spring, aspectj, load-time-weaving

I have built an application to test injecting log information (Entering and Exiting) around classes. I have built it using spring and used the following example for building it.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

It works great now but I have 2 issues:

- Private methods are not included when the log is weaved around the method. Is there a setting in the xml settings for spring to allow private methods to be weaved or is there another way around this?
- I have to include all packages that are to be weaved in the META-INF/aop.xml for this to be able to work. Is there a setting to be used so that the log information can be weaved for all classes created in the project without having to add the package name to the aop.xml.

Below I have included all code and xml that is used.  As I said all is working fine except the 2 issues above. Please assist me.

**app.java**

```
package se.jpab.application;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( new String[] { "spring.xml" });
        Client client = (Client) appContext.getBean("client");   
        Location clientLocation = (Location) appContext.getBean("location");        

//      Set all values
        clientLocation.setAdress1("Adress 1");
        clientLocation.setAdress2("Adress 2");
        clientLocation.setBox("N/A");
        clientLocation.setCity("City of Dallas");

        client.setName("John Doe");
        client.setUrl("http://www.url.com"); 
        client.setLocation(clientLocation);


 //     Print out all values        

        System.out.println(client.getName());        
        System.out.println(client.getUrl());
        System.out.println(client.getLocation().getAdress1());
        System.out.println(client.getLocation().getAdress2() + " " + client.getLocation().getCity());

    }
}
```

**Client.java**
    package se.jpab.application;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Client {

    String name;
    String url;
    Location location;
    //Constructors
    public Client(String custName, String custUrl, Location custLocation){
        name = custName;
        url = custUrl;  
        location = custLocation;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Client(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {      
        this.name = name;
        printThis(name);

    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public void printThis(String inStr) {
        System.out.println("PRIVAT METOD");
        System.out.println("Inkommand sträng --> " + inStr);
    }   


}
```

**Location.java**

```
package se.jpab.application;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Location {

    String city;
    String adress1;
    String adress2;
    String box;

    //Constructors  
public Location (String city, String adress1, String adress2, String box){

    this.city = city;
    this.adress1 = adress1;
    this.adress2 = adress2;
    this.box = box; 

}
public Location (){

}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getAdress1() {
    return adress1;
}
public void setAdress1(String adress1) {
    this.adress1 = adress1;
}
public String getAdress2() {
    return adress2;
}
public void setAdress2(String adress2) {
    this.adress2 = adress2;
}
public String getBox() {
    return box;
}
public void setBox(String box) {
    this.box = box;
}   
}
```

**aop.xml**

```
    <!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options=" -showWeaveInfo">
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->        
        <include within="se.jpab.application.*"/>
        <include within="se.jpab.aspect.*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->        
        <aspect name="se.jpab.aspect.InjectLogg"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

**Aspect**

```
package se.jpab.aspect;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class InjectLogg {

    private static final Log fallbackLogger = LogFactory.getLog(InjectLogg.class);

    @Around("execution(public * se.jpab.application..*.*(..))")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
                Object invoker = pjp.getThis();
                Log logger;

                logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClassNameFrom(invoker.getClass()));

                // Start injecting logg messages on entering a method.
                logger.info("ENTERING: (" + pjp.getSignature().getName() + ")");
                try {
                    logger.info("ARGUMENTS: " + Arrays.toString(pjp.getArgs()) + ")");
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    logger.info("ARGUMENTS: No arguments");
                }

                try {
                    // proceed to original method call
                    Object result = pjp.proceed();

                    // Injecting exiting messages after method is finished
                    logger.info("RESULT: " + result);
                    logger.info("EXITING: (" + pjp.getSignature().getName() + ")");

                    // Return the result of the method we are logging
                    return result;

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // same with ThrowsAdvice
                    logger.info("Exception. Throws IllegalArgumentException");
                    throw e;
                }

    }

    private String getClassNameFrom(Class invokerClassName) {
        // Function that ....... To be continued JP

        // Add check for that string contains $$ and se.goteborg if not then
        // return fallback logger class.

        String[] classNameParts = invokerClassName.getName().split("$$");
        int positionOfPackageName = classNameParts[0].indexOf("se.jpab");
        String className = classNameParts[0].substring(positionOfPackageName);

        return className;
    }
}
```

**Spring configuration (spring.xml)**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">


 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
 <context:load-time-weaver/>
 <context:annotation-config />
 <context:component-scan base-package="se.jpab"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Your first question:**

> Private methods are not included when the log is weaved around the
>   method. Is there a setting in the xml settings for spring to allow
>   private methods to be weaved or is there another way around this?

If you want to weave private methods, use full AspectJ and therein a privileged aspect, not Spring AOP. The [Spring manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) says:

> > *If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even
> >     constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving
> >     instead of Spring's proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a
> >     different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure
> >     to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.*

**Your second question:**

> I have to include all packages that are to be weaved in the
>   META-INF/aop.xml for this to be able to work. Is there a setting to be
>   used so that the log information can be weaved for all classes created
>   in the project without having to add the package name to the aop.xml.

You can catch a package an all its subpackages with the `..` syntax, e.g. `se.jpab.application..*` or even `se.jpab..*`. You can also combine several conditions with boolean operators. See the [AspectJ documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#configuring-load-time-weaving-with-aopxml-files) for examples.